# How do I determine if an assembly (DLL) is coming from the GAC or local binaries in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a legacy project that has a folder of shared binaries that various projects use. I know it would be better to use a nuget solution rather than a folder of shared binaries, but this legacy project environment won't allow that.

The problem that we have is that some other versions of these shared binaries already exist on engineer's machines (installed into the GAC I assume). Consequently when they add a reference they occasionally choose the system (GAC) instance rather than the project instance.

Then when we deploy to the remote targets that don't have their GAC version of the DLL installed, the application/web page doesn't work.

I've seen how references are added to the `csproj` XML file but I don't quite recognize how to determine if the reference will result in a GAC or not.

Is there a method in Visual Studio to determine if the DLL is coming from the GAC or from our shared library folder? If not within Visual Studio, is there a VS command line options for this? How about a way to conclusively recognize this in the `.sln` or `.csproj` files?

Comment: Use the debugger.  You see the paths where the DLLs were found both in the Output window and in the Debug > Windows > Module window.

Answer (score 2):

you can use gacutil.exe I believe

```
gacutil /l MyDll
```

Or you can do that from code:

```
if (!myDll.GlobalAssemblyCache)
{
     // not in GAC
}
```

Comment: `gacutil /l` shows what's installed in the GAC. Not what the project references. Just because it's installed doesn't mean we will use it. We have assemblies included in our projects that SHOULD be used, and there are also matching assemblies in the GAC that SHOULD NOT be used. I'm trying to detect this. I know how to do it via the Object Browser, but that is slow and cumbersome. Looking for a way to do it after the build has completed. Or even detect before the build completes.

Comment: We cannot do it from _inside_ the code because the code doesn't run when we have the GAC issue. Chicken and egg scenario. So we're looking for a way to either analyze the DLLs or interface with VS to get the information during the build/link process.